# Is it safe to always use overflow: hidden on the html tag?

Tags: html, css

Long story short, I've been using sprite sheets and some of them might have quite huge dimensions. To get the image I need, I use the css attribute `clip: rect(top, right, bottom, left)`, but something strange about clip is that whatever that is hidden is indeed not visible, but adds to horizontal (and probably vertical) scrolling to my browser when the browser window is small enough that part that would have been visible does not fit into the browser window even though they are not visible.

I found that adding a `overflow: hidden` attribute to any parent of the clipped image solves the problem.

The reason I'm asking here is, if it was my own pages, I'd just add that `overflow: hidden` to my `html` tag and be done with it. However, I'm making a jquery plugin and while I'm probably not skilled enough to make plugins that other people will use, I still want to make my plugins well behaved. If I add the css attribute through jquery to the html tag, would it cause unforeseen problems?

Comment: What if the page should actually be able to scroll?

Comment: There's only one way to find out but I'd approach it with a large content `div` just inside the `body`.

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` to the `<html>` tag will not have the same results as setting `overflow:hidden` on an individual elements using background image sprites.

Comment: Haha, I just realized that it indeed disables scrolling for the other elements, even those that are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using background position instead. As explained here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

It is more industry standard and you won't get those weird issues.